# IndexError while removing unwanted rows from csv

Tags: python, csv, dataset, data-cleaning, index-error

I dont know why I am getting this, i am trying to skip the rows containing '?' as column values. [Example of dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CfPM.jpg)

Example of csv file:

```
59, Private, 109015, HS-grad, 9, Divorced, Tech-support, Unmarried, White, Female, 0, 0, 40, United-States, <=50K
56, Local-gov, 216851, Bachelors, 13, Married-civ-spouse, Tech-support, Husband, White, Male, 0, 0, 40, United-States, >50K
19, Private, 168294, HS-grad, 9, Never-married, Craft-repair, Own-child, White, Male, 0, 0, 40, United-States, <=50K
54, ?, 180211, Some-college, 10, Married-civ-spouse, ?, Husband, Asian-Pac-Islander, Male, 0, 0, 60, South, >50K
39, Private, 367260, HS-grad, 9, Divorced, Exec-managerial, Not-in-family, White, Male, 0, 0, 80, United-States, <=50K
49, Private, 193366, HS-grad, 9, Married-civ-spouse, Craft-repair, Husband, White, Male, 0, 0, 40, United-States, <=50K
23, Local-gov, 190709, Assoc-acdm, 12, Never-married, Protective-serv, Not-in-family, White, Male, 0, 0, 52, United-States, <=50K
20, Private, 266015, Some-college, 10, Never-married, Sales, Own-child, Black, Male, 0, 0, 44, United-States, <=50K
45, Private, 386940, Bachelors, 13, Divorced, Exec-managerial, Own-child, White, Male, 0, 1408, 40, United-States, <=50K
30, Federal-gov, 59951, Some-college, 10, Married-civ-spouse, Adm-clerical, Own-child, White, Male, 0, 0, 40, United-States, <=50K
18, Private, 226956, HS-grad, 9, Never-married, Other-service, Own-child, White, Female, 0, 0, 30, ?, <=50K
```

I am using python and here is my code :

```
# Load the adult dataset
import csv
f = open("./adult_data.csv")
records = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ',')

# We define a header ourselves since the dataset contains only the raw numbers.
dataset = []
header = ['Age', 'Workclass', 'Fnlwgt', 'Education', 'Education-num', 'Marital-status', 'Occupation',
  'Relationship', 'Race', 'Sex', 'Capital-gain', 'Capital-loss', 'Hours-per-week', 'Native-    country', 'Salary'
]

for line in records:
  question_mark = True
for i in range(len(header)):
  if (line[i] == ' ?'):
    question_mark = False
if (question_mark):
  d = dict(zip(header, line))
d['Age'] = int(d['Age'])
d['Fnlwgt'] = int(d['Fnlwgt'])
d['Education-num'] = int(d['Education-num'])
d['Capital-gain'] = int(d['Capital-gain'])
d['Capital-loss'] = int(d['Capital-loss'])
d['Hours-per-week'] = int(d['Hours-per-week'])
dataset.append(d)
```

Here is my Output :

```
 Output
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-6-a6f851085aed> in <module>
      12     question_mark = True
      13     for i in range(len(header)):
 ---> 14         if(line[i] == ' ?'):
      15             question_mark = False
      16     if(question_mark):

 IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Can you update your question with sample data from the .csv file as well. It will be useful for others to reproduce the issue.

Comment: first use `print()` to see what you have in variables - `print(line)` and `print( len(line) )` and compare with `print( len(header) )`

Comment: you can also try `if ' ?' in line:` without `for`-loop

Comment: @Liju I have added some data examples

Comment: @MonalKumar Issue could not be reproduced. this code working fine with given data. Check if you are reading correct file.

Comment: @Liju yes I just ran it on sample data and it worked fine. I am reading the correct file, i think i have to look into dataset carefully. Link for the real dataset: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Adult. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @furas its better than for loop, thanks. It seems to work on a sample dataset but the problem persists on the real one.

Comment: @Liju It is working now, I opened the CSV in notepad and removes the last two blank lines. It was there in the CSV from the start. I didn't know that I had to remove this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lines

```
for i in range(len(header)):
  if (line[i] == ' ?'):
```

will raise an index error if, for example, there is an empty line at the end of the file, or if a row doesn't contain the expected number of cells.

You can get around this by iterating over the row directly, rather than accessing items by index (which might be considered poor style by some).

```
for cell in line:
    if cell == ' ?':
        ...
```

As Furas points out in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63831263/indexerror-while-removing-unwanted-rows-from-csv/63833842?noredirect=1#comment112880303_63833842), the code can be reduced further to

```
question_mark = (' ?' in line)
```

Comment: yes there was an empty line at the end of the file. I removed it manually and it's working now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think it can be reduced to `question_mark = (' ?' in line)`